# Creating an object of its own in a class, this is an endless recursion, why is JAVA allowed?

Tags: java, class

This is the code:

[image: code image]

The output is:

```
its a endless loop 10 
i = 10
```

Its a correct output, but on line 13, I can recursively aa wirelessly, why is this not a mistake?

I want to paste the code but the format doesn't work well, so sorry to let you see the picture.

Comment: 1) Paste the code, someone will format it for you if you can't. 2) I don't understand the question, what do you mean by "recursively aa wirelessly"?

Comment: Well, you _can_ write `.aa` as many times as possible, but you can only write it a finite amount of times before your computer runs out of memory/hard disk space. Java allowing you to access a static member on a instance _is_ a bit questionable, but if `aa` were non-static, the code definitely should be allowed to compile (and is). This is how linked lists are usually implemented in Java.

Comment: It's not an infinte loop. It's finite as you managed to write it down...

Answer (score 3):

This is not true recursion.  It is just doing a redundant operation a fixed number of times.

(Hint: there is no loop, and the repetition is not endless.)

Analogy:  `int i = 1; i++; i++; i++;` is not recursion either.

---

What is actually going on is a consequence of this section of [JLS 15.11.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.1):

> At run time, the result of the field access expression is computed as follows: (assuming that the program is correct with respect to definite assignment analysis, that is, every blank final variable is definitely assigned before access)
>
> - If the field is static:
>
>   - The Primary expression is evaluated, and the result is discarded. If evaluation of the Primary expression completes abruptly, the field access expression completes abruptly for the same reason.
>   - ...
>   - If the field is not final, or is a blank final and the field access occurs in a class variable initializer (§8.3.2) or static initializer (§8.7), then the result is a variable, namely, the specified class variable in the class that is the type of the Primary expression.

In your example, when you refer to `aa` in a method of `A`, that is another a way to refer to the class variable `A.aa`.

In theory, each `aa.` is causing a null check.  In practice, the JIT compiler should optimize that to just one.  But that is probably moot: if you care about performance you won't do this.

---

Why do they allow this in general?

It is generally acknowledge that allowing static variables to be accessed without qualification is a problem for code readability.  But they made that decision a long timed a go, and fixing it would be enormously disruptive.  So it has to stand.

---

Why do they allow the particular manifestation you have come across?

What you have written in your example is clearly pointless.  However, it is impractical to design a programming language to forbid pointless (but otherwise valid) usages of the language syntax.

---

Can you do anything about it?

IIRC, some Java style checkers, bug checkers and IDEs will warn you when you refer to a class variable without qualifying it; i.e. when you use `aa` rather than `A.aa`.